# Prompted for password after upgrading to Windows 10, but I used fingerprint in Windows 7

Tags: passwords, windows-10-upgrade

I just upgraded from 32-bit Windows 7 to Windows 10 on my tablet PC. I logged in to Windows 7 using fingerprint authentication. Now Windows 10 is prompting for a password to log in. None of my known passwords work, nor does not entering a password. I have yet to be able to get into Windows 10. How do I bypass the password prompt?

Comment: Enable the default Administrator account, once you do that, change the password to the user in question.

Comment: Can't get get past the login screen to do anything.

Comment: Boot to WinRE and enable the Administrator account that way.

Answer (score -1):

Restart the computer, and while it is starting up - access Safe Mode (usually by hitting F8 until you get a menu to do that).

When in Safe Mode, you will be able to go to Users in Control Panel, and disable the password.

Comment: F8 is not taking me into Safe Mode.

Comment: Even if I choose Safe Mode, it is still stops at the password prompt.

Comment: You cannot access Windows 10 safe mode with F8. This mistake indicates you didn't test your instructions out.

Comment: Can you provide the steps once I get toe the Win RE screen?

Comment: Even if I choose Command Prompt, it still stops at the password prompt.

Comment: I did test them, but forgot that F8 was enabled on my machine way back. So it does work for me, but not for everyone.

Comment: A tutorial for F8 enabling is [here](http://www.windows10forums.com/articles/enable-f8-safe-mode-boot-menu.8/), probably not useful in this case since it requires access to the machine.